# What is the reason for - java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: does not support java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec?

Tags: ssl, soap, axis

I am trying to authenticate my client application with the server over https - i am using axis 1.4 jar. I am passing the correct JKS file to the truststore. However, i am getting following exception.

```
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.throwSSLException(Handshaker.java:927)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:199)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    ... 26 more
  Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: does not support java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec
    at com.certicom.ecc.jcae.ECKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:304)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:910)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:195)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Are you using some third-party crypto provider (com.certicom..) ?

Comment: No i am not, whatever is part of axis.jar is what i am using

Comment: @Thilo : Sorry, i just looked at the code and it does use the com.certicom

Answer (score 1):

It was identified that the ECDH cipher suite is not part of java 1.6 setup by default which causes the exception of ECDH spec not supported.

This was fixed by added this spec which comes in the bcprov-jdk1.6.jar (bouncycastle) in the java setup. To do this do following changes

java/jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security\java.security

security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

[Note: security.provider.1 - numbering denotes the priority of choosing the cipher suite]

and add the bcprov-jdk1.6.jar inside jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\ext